# Hamming codes of the form [8,k,3] over $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: coding-theory

I want to determine all values of $q$ such that $C$ is an $[8,k,3]$ Hamming code over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Is there a way to do this that's not just computing every possible values of $q$? Since $k$ is fixed I thought there would be a way to use this, but I don't see it.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same as testing every possible value of $q$? Because I get $\frac{q^r-1}{q-1}=8$, and then I just solve for $q$.  But I don't see how to do that unless we specify $r$. For instance, if $r=2$, we get $q=7$. Do I have to do this for all $r$?

Comment: Ahh didn't think of using this. Thanks you very much!